# How do i extract inner dictionary from outer list

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to extract the inner dictionary from outer list ie remove the outer square brackets of the list.

example:

```
myList =[{'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3'},{'d':'4','e':'5'}]
```

Desire output:

```
{'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3'},{'d':'4','e':'5'}
```

Please note that inner dictionaries can be of dynamic size.

Any help would be great.

Comment: what's format you want? dict? str?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117912/python-accessing-values-in-a-list-of-dictionaries

Answer (score 3):

Just accessing the list element by index.

```
myList =[{'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3'},{'d':'4','e':'5'}]
d = myList[0]
```

So if you have `k` dictionaries in the list you need to access all of them, but this will be tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the list like any other list iteration:

```py
for i in myList:
    i # i is your dictionary
```

Comment: @Zhubei Federer :i need it in dictionary format

Comment: Wrong place to respond to him, but either answer given will give you dictionaries