# Python Accessing a Value in a List of Dictionaries, if another Value in the Dictionary Exists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

My question is an extension to this:

[Python Accessing Values in A List of Dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117912/python-accessing-values-in-a-list-of-dictionaries)

I want to only return values from dictionaries if another given value exists in that dictionary.

In the case of the example given in the linked question, say I only want to return 'Name' values if the 'Age' value in the dictionary is '17'.

This should output

```py
'Suzy'
```

only.

Comment: What have you done so far ? Or how would you do it ?

Comment: Questions should be self contained, provide an example of what you are talking about in this question

Comment: My only idea is to loop through the list of dictionaries to obtain the list indexes where the 'Age' value in the dictionary is '17', and then loop through those given indexes again to obtain the 'Name' value. But this feels inefficient, and my data set contains thousands of dictionaries.

Comment: You can loop only once. In the same loop, if the ```Age``` matches, you print the ```Name```. Only one loop ;)

Comment: @Metapod Good point. I guess I want some real pythonic script to do it, and something I can assign directly to a variable, as per Simon Hawe's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
result = [d["Name"] for d in dicts if d.get("Age") == 17)]
```

Of course this would select all nanes that satisfy the condition. You can put that in a function.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I was after, awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the following case :

```
listname= [  
    {'Name': 'Albert' , 'Age': 16},
    {'Name': 'Suzy', 'Age': 17},
    {'Name': 'Johnny', 'Age': 13}
]
```

If you want return only people Name when "age == 17" use :

```
for d in listname:
    if  d['Age'] == 17 :
        print (d['Name'])
```

Use a condition inside your for.

Edit 10/01/2022 : Change "list" to "listname", cause list il already reserved in python.

Comment: Take care to the naming. ```list``` is already reserved in Python